# How to persist initial data loaded with migrations between TransactionTestCases in Django Tests

Tags: django-testing

I am writing Django tests cases with `StaticLiveServerTestCase` in Django, with Playwright for browser automation.

Since `StaticLiveServerTestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase`, the data that I load in the Django migrations is lost between the test cases.

This is documented in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase), and also there is a [bug report here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25251).

Is there a good way around this? I am thinking of having an additinal fixture for initial data that will be loaded before each Test Case, but this will involve maintaing this fixture as the migrations add up.

Is there a better solution for this?